# JavaScript return from function only working once

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value

I want to give the addition of two random numbers and let the user input correct answer but its stuck to the same answer

```js
function start(){     
  var fst = document.getElementById("fst").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var snd = document.getElementById("snd").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);     
  return fst+snd;
} 
var x = start()
function validate(){
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value; 
  if(txt==x){   
    console.log('Correct Answer');    
  }  else  console.log('Wrong Answer'); 
  start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `validate()` function, you compare the user's input with `x`, then generate new random numbers by calling `start()`. However, the value of `x` is never updated, so the `x` is always equal to the first two random numbers that are generated.

Instead of calling `start()` at the end of the `validate()` function, assign `x` to the value of `start()` like this: `x = start()`.

This way, new random numbers will be generated, and the value of `x` will be assigned the sum of the new numbers.

Comment: Not Working, Now it showing wrong answer in first attempt as well